# Edit html certain element from chrome bookmark

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am running javascript by clicking a chrome bookmark to edit certain html element. When I run `javascript:void(console.log(document.getElementById("main_frame")))`, I got the result as shown in picture below. However, I could not get the element under the #document for example the 'container' in . How can I get the element under #document?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
var _iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow;
var _div =_iframe.document.getElementById('objId');
_div.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
```